# how do game implement customization of characters

Tags: game-design, character

I am looking to create a game a rpg. I want to add customization of character so that each players char is unique. How do i do it?

Comment: Hi welcome to GameDev SE! Unfortunately that type of question is just too broad, details might include very personal and subjective opinions instead of a single objective and correct way to answer. One could tell you to implement it in language X or Y, use library A or B over C, use the Foo method for this and the Bar method for that; while another user might tell you to use a completely different set of tech. Try to narrow your question to something more specific and do your research before asking. Good Luck!